# HTML - how to place text under another line of text when using display: inline or do it another way

Tags: html, css

I want to place the price of books underneath their own titles rather than placing underneath their images.

**Current Appearance:**
[image]

**search.html:**

```css
.resultContainer {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: black solid 1px;
}

.bookImage,
.bookTitle {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="resultContainer">
  <div style="display: inline;">
    <img class="bookImage" src=" https://marketplace.canva.com/MAB___U-clw/1/0/thumbnail_large/canva-yellow-lemon-children-book-cover-MAB___U-clw.jpg" alt="  book.title " width="120" height="160">
    <span class="bookTitle">
                Title Here<br/>
                <span class="bookPrice">
                    Price Here
                </span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="bookTitle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wondered that your question says to do this with `display: inline` and you accepted the answer `flexbox`

Comment: @Ramesh oh yeah you're right, I realise it now.

Comment: I added a answer using `inline`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to use [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

```css
.resultContainer {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
}

.bookImage,
.bookTitle {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="resultContainer">
  <img class="bookImage" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt=" {{ book.title }} " width="120" height="160">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <span class="bookTitle">
            Sample Book Title <br/>
            <span class="bookPrice">
                $399
            </span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="bookTitle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have solved my problem by using this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have asked a answer for `display:inline` I add this answer.

First of all you need to notice that nested span is a bad practice in your code. I removed the nest and wrapper with a `div`. Also I have wrapper for `img` as well. Since your parent is a `inline` element I made the wrappers (children elements) as `inline-block` elements which gives you the solution.

```css
.resultContainer {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: black solid 1px;
}

.bookImage,
.bookTitle,
.bookPrice {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.content-wrap,
.img-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="resultContainer">
  <div style="display: inline;">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img class="bookImage" src=" https://marketplace.canva.com/MAB___U-clw/1/0/thumbnail_large/canva-yellow-lemon-children-book-cover-MAB___U-clw.jpg" alt="  book.title " width="120" height="160">
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrap">
      <span class="bookTitle">Title Here</span>
      <br/>
      <span class="bookPrice">Price Here</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bookTitle"></div>
</div>
```